# Is the Bootstrap CSS on a CDN yet?

Tags: css, cdn, bootstrap

Just checking to see if anyone knows of a CDN for the bootstrap css framework.

Comment: Not sure why this is closed. Here's one answer: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know of a compressed version out there but you might want to create a saved Google search to keep yourself updated.

You could submit it to http://www.cdnjs.com and it has a shot being hosted by them for free.

Also, it looks like you could get an uncompressed version from here, http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.min.css.

Finally, if you wanted to, you could host a copy on your own CDN like Amazon's cloudshare.  It is very cheap to host and if you are using it only for your sites, it might only cost you a few dollars a month.

Comment: we are in the process of getting cdncss.com up and running. Feel free to come check it out http://github.com/cdnjs/cdncss

Comment: http://functionn.blogspot.com/2012/06/bootstrap-cdn-twitters-bootstrap-hosted.html <- there's also this now :)

Answer (score 7):

[Justin Dorfman](http://twitter.com/jdorfman) manages http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/ which has version 2.3.1 (at the time of editing)

**Complete CSS (Responsive, With Icons):**

[`//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css`](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css)

**Complete JavaScript**

[`//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js`](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js)

**GitHub Repo**

https://github.com/netdna/bootstrap-cdn

Answer (score 3):

The JS is available at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.3/bootstrap.min.js

Follow the CDNCSS at https://github.com/cdnjs/cdncss/tree/master/css/bootstrap

Update: The CSS can be found on cdnjs.com for now,
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as BootStrap is incredibly customisable, [including via their site](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html), wouldn't you be better off tailoring it (in the same way you might tailor the Modernizr JS packages) to more closely meet your requirements (such as colours and default font sizes, remove unused features, etc), and then host the (often much) smaller file your self?

Whilst there's some small benefit to not downloading the full payload if someone has already visited a site using it, there's still all the processing and parsing of the script that has to happen...

This is the route that Modernizr took with their move to version 2:

> [Modernizr and Content Delivery Networks](http://modernizr.com/news/modernizr-and-cdns/)